# Flutter, how to set max height to list view items

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

what I have tried is below.

```
         SizedBox(
           width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width * 0.88,
           height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height * 0.42,
             child: ListView.builder(
                   itemCount: 10,                          
                   itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
                            return _buildListItem();
                         }),
                   )
```

and the list widget

```
 Widget _buildListItem() {
    return ConstrainedBox(
      constraints: BoxConstraints(
        minHeight: 20,
          maxHeight: 120),
       child:Container(child:Text("Looooongggg textttttttttt 
              the text size is alwayysss different "),
       ),}
```

I want to make the list view item size dynamically, but also the max height is fixed at 120. In other words, no matter how long the text is, the container also wants to be to not go up to 120 or more.

This code always shows me only max height containers. No matter how short the letters are,

how could I achieve that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try IntrinsicHeight widget

```
Widget _buildListItem() {
    return ConstrainedBox(
      constraints: BoxConstraints(
        minHeight: 20,
          maxHeight: 120),
       child: IntrinsicHeight(child:Container(child:Text("Looooongggg textttttttttt 
              the text size is alwayysss different "),
       )),}
```

Comment: thanks! it works perfectly. I am just wondering, do you know any other method other than this one? I am just asking for my study purpose. If you can't think of it, you don't have to answer.

Comment: IntrinsicHeight is quite expensive, check the docs. You can avoid using it.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it by setting the scroll physics to *NeverScrollablePhysics*. By doing so List View would take enough height so that all its children can fit into it.
For example:-

```
    ...
    ListView.builder(
      physics:NeverScrollableScrollPhysics(),//this line would the change                               
      itemCount: 10,                          
      itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
              return _buildListItem();
            }),
           ),
    ...
```

Comment: Wrap the list view inside an Single child Scroll View Widget and enable shrink wrap true inside list view.This would help you .

Comment: appreciate it. I will refer that

Answer (score 0):

i did something funny, look

```
ConstrainedBox(
          constraints: BoxConstraints(
            minHeight: 50,
            maxHeight:
                (50 * (wallet.length < 3 ? wallet.length : 3)).toDouble(),
          ),
          child: ListView(
```

my listview shows a list of text widgets with the contents of my wallet list, i found that 50 is enought size for 1 item, so as maxHeight, i multiplied 50 by the number of lines, for up to 3 lines, so i wont waste space when my list have less than 3 items, and for more items, the listview will be scrollable.
i'm new to flutter and to programing in general, this is certainly not the best solution, but it worked for me.

Answer (score -1):

Use `Container` and assign min, max-height to `BoxConstraints`

```
Container(
        child: ListView.builder(itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, index) {
            return Container(
              constraints: BoxConstraints(minHeight: 20, maxHeight: 40),
              color: Colors.red,
              child: Divider(),
            );
        }, itemCount: itemsList.length,),
      ),
```

**Output:**

[image]

Comment: This is pretty much the same as the code I've already put in the question. Except that the container and constrained properties are swapped back and forth.

Comment: This will maintain min and max height constraint, This works

Comment: I just did it that you have suggested. and it does not work. it always show max height

Comment: That may be because your child is too big, its taking max 40